# Pandas DataFrame.hist Seaborn equivalent

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

When exploring a I often use Pandas' DataFrame.hist() method to quickly display a grid of histograms for every numeric column in the dataframe, for example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets


data = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

df.hist(bins=50, figsize=(10,7))
plt.show()
```

Which produces a figure with separate plots for each column:
[image: Which produces a figure with separate plots for each column]

I've tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn import datasets


data = datasets.load_iris()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)

for col_id in df.columns:
    sns.distplot(df[col_id])
```

But this produces a figure with a single plot and all columns overlayed:
[image: But this produces a figure with a single plot and all columns overlayed]

Is there a way to produce a grid of histograms showing the data from a DataFrame's columns with Seaborn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no equivalent as seaborn `displot` itself will only pick 1-D array, or list,  maybe you can try generating the subplots.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 10))

for i in range(ax.shape[0]):
    for j in range(ax.shape[1]):
        sns.distplot(df[df.columns[i*2+j]], ax=ax[i][j])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that produced something close to what I was after.

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of seaborn's FacetGrid if you reorganize your dataframe using `melt`. Seaborn typically expects data organized this way (long format).

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df.melt(), col='variable', col_wrap=2)
g.map(plt.hist, 'value')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this looks to be the cleanest way to get something close to df.hist()

Comment: To make the histograms easier to compare you can set the bin width using `sns.histplot`instead of `plt.hist`, like this: `g.map(sns.histplot, 'value', binwidth=0.5)`. Or if you prefer choosing a certain number of bins to cover the whole range of values, you can use this instead: `_, bin_edges = np.histogram(df.melt()['value'], bins=10); g.map(sns.histplot, 'value', bins=bin_edges)` (tested with seaborn v. 0.11.0)

Answer (score 0):

https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/distplot_options.html

Here is an example how you can show 4 graphs using subplot, with seaborn.

Comment: The link for the image on the page you have shared is broken and `distplot` appears to be deprecated in the current version of seaborn. Would you care to share a new link to another working example or to recreate the image with some code yourself and share the result here so that people may use it?

Answer (score 0):

Anothert useful SEABORN method to quickly display a grid of histograms for every numeric column in the dataframe for you could be the quick,clean and handy sns.pairplot()

try:
`sns.pairplot(df)`
this has a lot of cool parameters you can explor like Hue etc

[pairplot example for iris dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8hNr.png)

if you DON'T want the scatters you can actually create a customised grid really really quickly using `sns.PairGrid(df)`
this creates an empty grid with all the spaces and you can map whatever you want on them :`g = sns.pairgrid(df)`

```
`g.map(sns.distplot)` or `g.map_diag(plt.scatter)`
```

etc

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adapting jcaliz's to make it work more generally, i.e. not just when the DataFrame has four columns, I also added code to remove any unused axes and ensure axes appear in alphabetical order (as with `df.hist()`).

```
size = int(math.ceil(len(df.columns)**0.5))
fig, ax = plt.subplots(size, size, figsize=(10, 10))

for i in range(ax.shape[0]):
    for j in range(ax.shape[1]):
        data_index = i*ax.shape[1]+j
        if data_index < len(df.columns):
            sns.distplot(df[df.columns.sort_values()[data_index]], ax=ax[i][j])

for i in range(len(df.columns), size ** 2):
    fig.delaxes(ax[i // size][i % size])
```